# Redirecting User to home page when not logged in and trying to access a certain web page vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Ok so far i have working the ability to log in and access a certain web page ('bookrepair.aspx') through the use of roles and permissions. I used this to then deny any non-logged on users which works however it throws me up the "Server in '/' Application error". However i would like it to redirect the user to the home page ('home.aspx') and display a message to them saying "Only logged in users can access Book Repair"

So for i have this piece of code in my 'bookrepair.aspx' page

```
Private Sub Pages_BookRepair_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")
        MsgBox("Only logged in user's can access Book Repair")
    End If
End Sub
```

However i still get the "Server in '/' Application error when trying to access it not logged in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps not related to your error, but you can't use `MsgBox` in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @Mark oh never got an error so thought it would work, my bad. What are my options for a message box in ASP.NET?

Comment: Redirect the user to a page that displays the message you want them to see when they are not logged on is the best way.

Comment: @PrescottChartierhave just tried that but i still get the same error?

Comment: I assume you are still using `User.Identity`, and that is where the error is occurring that's not really clear.  Check the server's application log to see what the error is, if in the IDE, the error will be on the page returned by the IDE, post it here.  Again, I would switch to using the session or ViewState object to manage this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the User.Identity functionality just because of all the issues you have to address in order to authenticate users.  I make it simple and set a flag in either the Session or ViewState object which would indicated whether or not the user is logged on.  For example:

```
If Session("LoggedOn") = "NO" Then
    Response.Redirest("MainPage.aspx", False) 'False to indicate that the rest of the code in the procedure is not to be executed.
End IF
```

It's what works best for me, I have total control over it, do not have to worry that the browser supports it because Session is maintained on the server.  I've never had an issue with it.